# How to get text for div close to button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the text of some div within the parent div where button is clicked. This is an example code

```
    <div class="parentDiv" >
        <div id="divToFind" style="display:none">text</div>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="button" type="button" >Remove</button>
        </div>
    </div>                 

    <div class="parentDiv" >
        <div id="divToFind" style="display:none">text2</div>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="button" type="button">Remove</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here parentDiv is repeated couple of times and text of divToFind is different in each parentDiv. Whenever remove button is clicked within the parentDiv I want to get the text of divToFind.

I have tried this

```
$(this).closest('.parentDiv').children('#divToFind').text();
```

But nothing is returned

Comment: Don't use two same ID's in single document.

Comment: funny people give -1 without telling why. is it for mistake in question or because they didn't like you made the mistake. if it is for latter then it is defeating the whole purpose of stackoverflow. it is like dis-couraging a person from asking a question.

Comment: @jss For clarification, I did **not** give you -1. And I think the question is fine.

Comment: @jas This site is really bad for that - don't take it personally.  I think there's nothing wrong with your question but many SO'ers are quick to downvote.  It's a big problem with this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use same IDs in a single document. You should use classes instead. With class, it works fine.

It is mentioned in the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id) that there must not be multiple elements in a document that have the same id value.

```js
$(function(){
  $("button").on("click", function(){
    var t = $(this).closest('.parentDiv').children('.divToFind').text();
    console.log(t);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parentDiv" >
    <div class="divToFind" style="display:none">text</div>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="button" type="button" >Remove</button>
    </div>
</div>                 
<div class="parentDiv" >
    <div class="divToFind" style="display:none">text2</div>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="button" type="button">Remove</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Its true, you should not use same Id for 2 elements in an HTML document, However following is the code that can help you to get the text of the div given.

There are 2 ways:

```
$(this).parent().prev('#divToFind').text();

$(this).parent().prev().text();
```

prev and next allows us to traverse on the same level. You can provide selectors inside that to get particular element.

In your example its ID, you can update Id to some css class, so that you dont have to have elments with same ID.